# npm UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY in docker behind corporate firewall

Tags: docker, npm, ssl-certificate

I am getting an error running npm as root in a Dockerfile.

```
 > [runner  5/10] RUN npm install --global pm2:
#0 71.79 npm ERR! code UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY
```

We have an antivirus/corporate firewall that we can't turn off, which substitutes SSL certificates to inspect traffic.

My problem is that because `npm install --global pm2` is running as root, it does not honor `export NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=/path/to/my-cacert.crt`.

I tried with `RUN npm config set cafile /path/to/my-cacert.crt`, but that also didn't work for some reason.

How can I fix `UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY` when running npm as root in a docker container?

This dockerfile reproduces the issue:

```
FROM node:alpine AS deps

COPY my.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
RUN cat /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/my.crt >>/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

RUN npm install --global pm2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You post your Dockerfile it will be helpful,

but there are multiple options for You.

1- instead of using `export` set your `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS` with `ARG` option in dockerfile, it will be used for all users does not matter if You change your user between builds like this:

```
FROM node:alpine AS deps

ARG NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

COPY my.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
RUN cat /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/my.crt >>/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

RUN npm install --global pm2
```

But if You set a variable with `export` it will be used just for that `RUN` entry which You used `export`. Remember if You are doing multi stage build `ARG` is scoped to their stage, and if You need to set this in different stages, You have to use your `ARG` in each stage.

2- to use http instead of https(it is not secure but usable). You can [set](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-config/#set) it within your configuration like:
`npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/`

3- add your CA certificate to trusted certificates within your Dockerfile like:

```
...
COPY ca.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ca.crt
RUN apt update && \
  apt install -y ca-certificates && \
  update-ca-certificates
...
```

Comment: I updated the question with a sample Dockerfile.

Comment: Actually, your solution with `ARG NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` worked. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, I'll award the bounty to you as soon as the system allows it.